# not accessing old data on mongodb atlas by Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have not used mongodb atlas for 10 days.
when I am trying to connect node application after 10 days into mongodb atlas  returning blank array in find Query from Node application , when I inserted new data into mongodb atlas using Node application then find Query return only new data .

Problem is that mongodb atlus not returning old data.
but App collection have

```
 db.apps.count({})  >  29
```

Code

```
let mongoose  = require("mongoose");   
let uri = mongodb atlus path ||  "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";   
mongoose.connect(uri, function (err, client) {   
console.log('mongoose connect SuccessFully');});       
let appSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name:{type: String}});    
let taxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({tax:{type: String}});    
var App = mongoose.model('App', appSchema);    
var Tax = mongoose.model('Tax', taxSchema);    
App.find({}).then(function (apps) {       
console.log(apps); // returning  [] "   
}); 
Tax.find({}).then(function (tax) {   
    console.log(tax); // returning  []  
});
```

facing problem with old data of mongodb atlas  not giving.
Every Query returns null or array depend upon what Query you have . I am stuck from past one day with mongodb atlas.
this code work fine with local mongodb .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This does not sound like a question for here. I think you need to contact Atlas support for this if what you are saying is your previously existing data is missing. The StackOverflow community can help you with coding problems, but has not influence over provider support or storage.

Comment: Your old data might be in a different database. By default, you are connecting to the `test` database. Open the "Cluster" section of Atlas console, Click on "collections". You will see different databases on the cluster and the collections and data inside them. See if you can find your old data in one of those.

Comment: thanks @DushyantBangal . working Fine

Comment: @RahulModanwal, good to know. I've posted it as an answer for other users.

Comment: my be old data is stored with different schema...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your old data might be in a different database.**

**By default, you are connecting to the test database.**

To see the different databases and collections, the easiest way is:

1. Open the "Cluster" section of Atlas console
2. Click on "collections".
   You will see different databases on the cluster and the collections
   and data inside them.
3. See if you can find your old data in one of
   those

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I didn't properly update the new `mongodb+srv//***` connection string I got from Atlas "connect menu".

Was trying to connect to:

```
mongodb+srv://user:pwd@host/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

But needed to use following:

```
mongodb+srv://user:pwd@host/MY_DATABASE_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```